# Как узнать изменение файлов в Гите

Tags: git

Как через команду в Гите, можно узнать в каких местах и в каких файлах были совершены изменения??

Comment: `git-blame`, но лучше использовать нормальную IDE

Comment: [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Comment: `tig` - но нужно ставить. удобно для быстрого просмотра. А также `tig blame имя-файла`